# Creating a List in python for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Before i go on, let me say that i have searched the Internet for clarification before i am asking it here.I have a class

```
class Course(ndb.model):
  tutor = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  ...
```

and a `Student` class.
I want to include in the `Course` class a list of Students (represented by their id)registered on the course.From my search, i came across options like `StringListProperty()` from [this](http://bookmarks.honewatson.com/2010/07/13/app-engine-stringlistproperty-merge-join-attributes-pattern/) website and `class ListProperty(item_type, verbose_name=None, default=None, ...)` from the [Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ListProperty) tutorial on Types and Property Classes.I am still confused as to which is the right way to do this.I need a layman's explanation and possibly a guide to where i can find a tutorial with example.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a bunch of options, but probably the most straight forward is to use a `ndb.KeyProperty` with `repeated=True`.  The values will be the `key` of your particular student.  e.g.:

```
class Student(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Course(ndb.Model):
    students = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

def create_course(students):
    """Create a new course object and return it.

    Args:
        students: iterable of `Student` model instances.
    """
    c = Course()
    c.students = [s.key for s in students]
    return c
```

Comment: It would be a classmethod of the Course class.  This approach has some potential down sides.  If you have large numbers of students it may not scale.  You may find that you have an enrolment for each year in the course.  Also you would probably want to manage adding students to the course after the fact. Do you need to record date of enrollment, can students join during a course duration - ie semester etc.....

Comment: Can students be enrolled in more than one course? Do you need to keep historical details about past enrollments ?

Comment: No,students cannot be enrolled in more than one course.And a course can have a maximum of 10 students.I haven't thought about keeping such details but might be added,